# X-Cart 5.5.1 module archive structure

Tags: module, x-cart

How to create the file .phar/.metadata.bin that mentioned in the error message during the XC5 module file upload? And what is the file structure that is required in the X-Cart 5.5.1 module archive?

No documentation about the X-Cart 5.5.1 module archive structure and the file .phar/.metadata.bin provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 5.5 apps please follow https://developer.x-cart.com/migration_guides/updating_modules_from_5.4_to_5.5_branch#packing-an-add-on

Make sure you use command param "--source=local", not "--source=git"